# Select only certain columns in related model when eager loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two related models:

```
class Attribute extends Eloquent
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Attribute');
    }
}
```

I want to return all attributes and their categories as a JSON object, but I only want to select certain fields in both models (i.e. not return fields like 'created_at' in the JSON).

I've tried this:

```
$attributes = Attribute::select('id', 'name')
 ->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
   $query->select('categories.id', 'categories.name', 'categories.attribute_id');
 }]);

Response::JSON($attributes->get());
```

but despite the select query for the related model, unrequested fields are returned:

```
attributes: [{
 id: 3,
 name: "Organisation",
 categories: [{
  id: 3,
  name: "Asia HQ",
  attribute_id: 3,
  created_at: "2013-11-30 00:00:00",
  updated_at: "2013-11-30 00:00:00"
 }]
}]
```

How do I select only certain columns in related model when eager loading?

Comment: Similar thing was solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727038/laravel-eloquent-how-to-get-only-certain-columns-from-joined-tables

Comment: Check what query was executed, because for `hasMany` it works as expected.

Comment: @delmadord I understand I can set $hidden and $visible in the model. But I need to show different fields on different pages, so I'd like a dynamic solution.

Comment: @MMacdonald You should check transformers - this is what you need. And again - the code you pasted is working as expected (L4.2), so either it's `belongsToMany` relation, which is bugged ineed, or you miss something.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of select() laravel method:

```
$attributes = Attribute::select('id', 'name')->with(['categories' =>function($query){
        $query->select(['categories.id', 'categories.name','categories.attribute_id'])->get();
}]);

Response::JSON($attributes->get());
```

To make select method work in eager loading you need to include foreign_key in 
selected column list.

**Reference** : http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/column-selection-in-eager-loading

Answer (score 2):

What about an eloquent method that will look like this?

```
public function dynamicAttributes($array_columns) {
  return $this->belongs_to('User')->select((array) $array_comuns);
}
```

Where `$array_columns` could be a string or array of strings representing a columns you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **always** return those specific fields from the categories relation, defining the select in the relationship will work, but if you would like to do it on the fly for one specific query, ask Eloquent to only return those fields.

```
$attributes = Attribute::with(['categories' => function ($query) {
   $query->select('id', 'name', 'attribute_id');
 }])->get('id', 'name');
```

... Or you could use Fluent

```
DB::table('attributes')
            ->join('categories', 'attributes.id', '=', 'categories.attribute_id')
            ->select('attributes.id', 'attributes.name', 'categories.id', 'categories.name', 'categories.attribute_id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$attributes = Attribute::select('id', 'name')
    ->with([
      'categories:categories.id,categories.name,categories.attribute_id',
    ]);

Response::JSON($attributes->get());
```

Please notice: **no space** after comma in argument list