# Convert raw query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, inner-join

How to convert this raw query to Laravel eloquent way:

```
select c.name as country from country c, address ad, city ci where
ad.id = 1 and city.id = ad.city_id and c.code = ci.country_code
```

Answer (score 3):

[First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801859/laravel-eloquent-filter-by-column-of-relationship)

[Second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727038/laravel-eloquent-how-to-get-only-certain-columns-from-joined-tables)

[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries)

```
DB::table("country")
->join('city', 'city.country_code', '=', 'country.user_id')
->join('address', 'address.city_id', '=', 'city.id')
->select('country.name as country')
->where('address.id', 1)
->get();
```

[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

```
Country::with(['city','address' => function($query){
    return $query->where('id', 1)
}])
->select('country.name as country')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! ur Query Builder method is running, but Eloquent way shows 

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Comment: @WahidNahiyan `city` and `address` are relations in the Country model and both must be declared.

Comment: yes u are right .. in large project sometimes it is hard to manage Models along with other models as many dev are working and some are less experience and some has more .. I think Query Builder approach is pretty straight forward and easy to understand where Eloquent has its own methods and declarations on Model.. What is your Opinion ??

Thanks once again for help !!

Comment: @WahidNahiyan, I like Eloquent approach, because it more flexible for me. 

I use Query Builder if need get aggregate information for more than one table (example, search). If I work with one table, use Eloquent.

Comment: yea Me too !! in case of One table Eloquent is nice.. but in case of joining or complex query i found it complex (may be my lack) , i used to write DB::raw expression but now feel that Query Builder can do this in nicer way..

Answer (score 3):

I will modify the answer from **`Andrey Lutscevich`** eloquent part

```
Country::select('country.name as country')->has('city')
  ->whereHas('address', function ($query)
  {
    $query->where('id', 1);
  })
  ->get();
```

> **Querying Relationship Existence**
>   When accessing the records for a model, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship use **`has`** in that case
>
> **`WhereHas methods put "where" conditions on your has queries`**

Comment: Thanks for help , but it shows 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::city()

Comment: @WahidNahiyan you have to create relations in your model