# four tables joins in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

this query is for codeigniter how to make it in laravel eloquent

```
 $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('countries cun'); 
            $this->db->join('cities cit', 'cit.country_code=cun.country_code', 'left');
            $this->db->join('city_states cits', 'cits.country_code=cun.country_code', 'left');
            $this->db->join('timezone timz', 'timz.country_code=cun.country_code', 'left');
            $this->db->where('cun.country',$id);         
           return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
return DB::table('countries AS cun')
    ->leftJoin('cities AS cit', 'cit.country_code', '=', 'cun.country_code')
    ->leftJoin('city_states AS cits', 'cits.country_code', '=', 'cun.country_code')
    ->leftJoin('timezone AS timz', 'timz.country_code', '=', 'cun.country_code')
    ->where('cun.country', $id)
    ->get();
```

**Eloquent Model**

```
return Country::leftJoin('cities AS cit', 'cit.country_code', '=', 'countries.country_code')
     ->leftJoin('city_states AS cits', 'cits.country_code', '=', 'countries.country_code')
     ->leftJoin('timezone AS timz', 'timz.country_code', '=', 'countries.country_code')
     ->where('countries.country', $id)
     ->get();
```

Comment: my question is in  eloquent model not a query builder

Comment: Okay. I have update the answer. Check this and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293971/convert-raw-query-to-larvel-eloquent/)

`Countries::with(["cities", "city_states", "timezone"])->where("country", $id)->get();`

`Countries` - Eloquent Model.

`cities`, `city_states`, `timezone` - [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) in the `Countries` model.