# Laravel "where" query the relationship table

Tags: laravel

This is my query:

```
$items = UserItems::with('item')
            ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
            ->where('quantity','>',0)
            ->where('items.type','=',"shirt")
            ->get();
```

I need all items where `type` is `shirt`.

The query returns this:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.type' in 'where clause'`

For some reasons, the `items` is not recognized as a table in this query, and I can't use `where on it.

Then how I can get all user items where the item type is `shirt`?

Comment: is your table called 'item' or 'items'? if so, change -> with('item') to  with('items'), if not, change -> ->where('items.type','=',"shirt") to ->where('item.type','=',"shirt")

Comment: I tried both, it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will actually need to use `whereHas` to handle this...

```
$items = UserItems::with('item')
        ->whereHas('item', function($q) {
            $q->where('type', 'shirt');
         })
        ->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
        ->where('quantity','>',0)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Decision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37294300/3894654)

Try:

```
$items = UserItems::with(['item' => function($query){
    return $query->where("type", "shirt")
})
->where('user_id','=',$this->id)
->where('quantity','>',0)
->get();
```