# Select specific columns on eager loading polymorphic relationships - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In a "normal" relationship I can do something like this to select only a few columns while eager loading (using with):

```
->with(['reported' => function ($query) { $query->select(['nick','id']); } ])
```

But how to do it when working with polymorphic relationship where the columns i want to select are different according to the model morphed?

I have already tried using the query like a normaly do, also tried using a morph clause, but there is no select funciton on it.

--
Edited:

```
ReportMessages (model)

public function author(){
return $this->morphTo();
}

User (model)

protected $fillable = ['name', (...)];

public function reportMessages(){
return $this->morphOne('App\ReportMessage', 'author');
}

Jogador (model)
protected $fillable=['nick', (...)];

public function reportMessages(){
return $this->morphOne('App\ReportMessage', 'author');
}
```

And i want to select (when eager loading) only the nick ,when it is Jogador model that is morphed, and only the name, when User is the model morphed.

Comment: Post the code that didn't work

Comment: $query->with(['author' => function($query){ $query->select(['id','name','nick']) } ])->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

Where nick is from one model and name from the other. (and author is the morphed relationship)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$query->with(['reported' => function($query){ $query->select(['id','nick']) } ])->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Sorry, i didnt explained correctly. I edited my question to contain more details.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select specific columns per polymorphic  relation you can use **constrain**

Having a commentable like the name of the morph that can be a Post model or a Video, in order to recover distinct columns per each model we can put the following code:

```
$comments = Comment::with(['commentable' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
    $morphTo->constrain([
        Post::class => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['hidden_at']);
        },
        Video::class => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['type', 'educational']);
        },
    ]);
}])->get();
```