# Select specific column from morph relation according to type in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-8

I am trying to write a query that selects columns from a model then selects some columns from a morph relationship table. But I have no idea to select columns, and relation tables have different columns. So some column has no slug, some have.

```
public function index()
{
    $menus = Menu::whereActive(true)
        ->with([
            'menuable' => function ($q) {
                // This gives error if  there is no relation Pages model
                $q->whereActive(true)->select('pages.id', 'pages.slug');

                // Below not working
                // if($q->type === Page::class){
                //    $q->whereActive(true)->select('pages.id', 'pages.slug');
                // } else if($q->type === Category::class){
                //     $q->whereActive(true)->select('categories.id', 
                           'categories.slug');
                // }
            }
        ])
        ->get(['id', 'menuable_id', 'menuable_type', 'name']);

    $response = [
        'menus' => $menus,
    ];

    return $this->sendResponse($response);
}
```

**Models**

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    public function menuable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Page extends Model
{
    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Menu::class, 'menuable');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Menu::class, 'menuable');
    }
}
```

How can I select specific columns from morph relation with checking morph type? I am using Laravel version 8.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043886/select-specific-columns-on-eager-loading-polymorphic-relationships-laravel/76742334#76742334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polymorphic relation is something the **Eloquent** aware of, and DBMS hasnot implemented this feature in it.
so there **cannot be** a sql query which join a table to another *tables* based on the morph column.

so you have to use distinct queries for every polymorphic join relation on your models:

```
//you can retrieve distinct menu based on their relation 
Menu::whereActive(true)->hasPage()->with('pages');

//and having the ralations in the menu model:
public function posts
Menu::whereActive(true)->hasCategory();

//scope in menu class can be like:
public function scopePage($query){
    return $query->where('menuable_type',Page::class);
}
public function scopeCategory($query){
    return $query->where('menuable_type',Category::class);
}

//with these you can eager load the models
Menu::whereActive(true)->hasPage()->with('page');
Menu::whereActive(true)->hasCategory()->with('category');

public function page(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}
public functioncategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

if you want a common interface to use one of these dynamically.
you can use:

```
$menu->menuable->id
$menu->menuable->slug
```

---

I am not sure which columns you want to response, but as i can guess from your question, I suppose you want `id` and `slug` from both models.

```
public function index(){
    $pagedMenu = Menu::whereActive(true)->hasPage()->with('page');
    $categoriedMenu = Menu::whereActive(true)->hasCategory()->with('category');

    $menues = $pagedMenu->merge($categoriedMenu);
    
    $response = [
        'menus' => $menus,
    ];

    return $this->sendResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: This not helps me

Comment: what do you want exactly? what is your requirements?

Comment: Can you show me complete code for index function?

Comment: does this help you?

Answer (score 3):

You can perfom separate filters based on the morph-class. This can be achieved with the `whereHasMorph` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships).

If you need to automatically resolve the relationship you can use `with`. This will preload morphables automatically into your resulting collection.

The following example uses an `orWhere` with 2 separate queries per morphable.

```
$menus = Menu::whereActive(true)

    ->whereHasMorph('menuable', [Page::class], function (Builder $query) {
        // perform any query based on page-related entries
    })

    ->orWhereHasMorph('menuable', [Category::class], function (Builder $query) {
        // perform any query based on category-related entries
    })

    ->with('menuable')

  ;
```

An alternative way is to pass both classes to the second argument. In that case you can check the type inside your closure.

```
$menus = Menu::whereActive(true)

    ->whereHasMorph('menuable', [Page::class, Category::class], function (Builder $query, $type) {

        // perform any query independently of the morph-target
        // $q->where...

        if ($type === (new Page)->getMorphClass()) {
            // perform any query based on category-related entries
        }

        if ($type === (new Category)->getMorphClass()) {
            // perform any query based on category-related entries
        }
    })

    ->with('menuable')
```

If required you can also preload nested relationships. (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading-morphto-relationships)

```
$menus = Menu::whereActive(true)

    ->with(['menuable' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
        $morphTo->morphWith([
            Page::class => ['calendar'],
            Category::class => ['tags'],
        ]);
    }])
```

Comment: This only helps to filter data. I need with relation (show related model IN RESPONSE), and select only specific columns from relation.

Comment: @Benfactor In this case you can use `with`. I have updated my answer. Additionally provided an example how you could load relationships based on each morphable. This was not asked but might be helpful.