# How to select specific columns in a polymorphic relationship where table columns are different?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I only select specific columns in a polymorphic relationship because the table columns are different?

```
$query->with(['Postable' =>function($query){
   $query->select('business_title','name ','last_name');
}
```

The business_title column exists in the agency table. Name and last_name exist in the user table. If I select one table other table gets an error of column not found.

Comment: See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043886/select-specific-columns-on-eager-loading-polymorphic-relationships-laravel/76742334#76742334 the solution is use constrain

Answer (score 0):

Either develop a naming convention that fulfills your needs (ex: columns like 'name', 'title' can be found on many tables), or do not use `select` in your query and get all coulmns: `$query->with(['Postable']);` and you would need appropriate ways to read your query results. Or simply use multiple queries to read from different tables which seems to be the rational option.

Comment: thank you Reza Jan, can you help write my own script for it? just give me some clues