# How to select columns from joined tables: laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a different problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727038/laravel-eloquent-how-to-get-only-certain-columns-from-joined-tables). The scenario is same but I am in need of more filtration of the results.

Let me explain.

Consider I have 2 tables

vehicles

```
 id
 name
 staff_id
 distance
 mileage
```

staffs

```
 id
 name
 designation
```

I want to select only `id` and `name` from both tables(Models).
The Vehicle Model contain a `belongsTo` relation to Staff model.

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public function staff()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Staff','staff_id');
    }
}
```

and I joined using this

```
Vehicle::where('id',1)
            ->with(['staff'=> function($query){
                            // selecting fields from staff table
                            $query->select(['staff.id','staff.name']);
                          }])
            ->get();
```

When I put fields in `->get()` like this

```
->get(['id','name'])
```

it filters the `vehicle` table but produce no result of Staff table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found it.. 
In the `->get()` you have to put the 'staff_id' like this

```
Vehicle::where('id',1)
            ->with(['staff'=> function($query){
                            // selecting fields from staff table
                            $query->select(['staff.id','staff.name']);
                          }])
            ->get(['id','name','staff_id']);
```

Since I didn't take the `staff_id`, it couldn't perform the join and hence staff table fields were not shown.

Answer (score 11):

You can use normal join like this:

```
Vehicle::join('staff','vehicles.staff_id','staff.id')
         ->select(
                  'vehicles.id',
                  'vehicles.name',
                  'staff.id as staff_id',
                  'staff.name'
          )
         ->get();
```

Since, you can't take both `id` at once in a join because only one is allowed. So, you can staff's id as `staff_id`.

You can add vehicle id condition with where clause like:

```
Vehicle::join('staff','vehicles.staff_id','staff.id')
         ->where('vehicle.id',1)
         ->select(
                  'vehicles.id',
                  'vehicles.name',
                  'staff.id as staff_id',
                  'staff.name'
          )
         ->get();
```

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest and more convenient way I guess would be :

```
Vehicle::select('id','name','staff_id')->where('id',1)
->with('staff:id,name' )->get();
```

foreign key should present for selection .

Since Laravel 5.7 you can use with() like this :

```
with('staff:id,name' )
```

for granular selection.