# Laravel - Select specific columns from joined relationship models using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to select specific columns from tables that I have joined using Eloquent.

I have 3 models
- Transaction
- Channel
- Merchant

Transactions links to Channel. It has a hasOne relationship.
Channel links to Merchant. It also has a hasOne relationship.

```html
public function channel() {
    return $this->hasOne(Channel::class, 'uuid', 'entityId');
}
```

```html
public function merchant() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Merchant', 'uuid', 'sender');
}
```

I'm using eager loading so have the following in the Transaction model:

```html
protected $with = ['channel'];
```

And Channel has:

```html
protected $with = ['merchant']:
```

This the query I'm trying to convert into Eloquent but I'm unsure how to select columns when they belong to related models. What I don't get is that if the relationships have been defined, why can't I select columns from the other models without having to reuse joins or the with clause?

```html
SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS amount, 
       m.name 
FROM transactionsV2 t JOIN
     channels c
     ON t.entityId = c.uuid JOIN
     merchants m
     ON c.sender = m.uuid
WHERE t.paymentType = 'DB' AND
      t.status = 1 AND
      t.processing_time >= '2019-01-01' AND
      t.processing_time < '2019-01-21'
GROUP BY m.name;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select columns from joined tables: laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437607/how-to-select-columns-from-joined-tables-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: I've seen this but I've declared "with" in the models. Why would I need to declare it again in the query?

Comment: Laravel uses mutiple queries to get relations, it's not using JOIN statement. That's why you can't use columns from related model so easily

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `protected $with = ['merchant:id,name'];` or maybe use [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) like `selectRaw('SUM(t.amount) AS amount, m.name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
Transaction::sum('amount')
    ->whereStuf(...)
    ->with(['channel.merchant' => function($query){
        $query->select('name')
            ->groupBy('name');
    }])->get();
```

The `channel.merchant` allows you to get the nested relation.

Comment: This is what I've done before and it's worked but I've declared "with" in the models themselves as a protected property so why would I do it again in the query.

Comment: Look my comment, Laravel will use multiple queries to get your `with` relations. So you can't query the columns, since they are not included in the global query. You must use the closures.

Comment: If that's the case, why even have the feature of declaring with as a protected property in the model? You'll just be repeating yourself every time.

Comment: The `with` allows eager loading, and it will be convenient enough in 95% of the cases (just get relations data). What you can do is write your own relation function in your model to make it easy.

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to include merchant.name in the select? Your code works but I want to be able to specify column names?