# Laravel 5.4 join with identical columns names

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables I want to join.

table: users
table: orders

users and orders have a column called 'id'

I need to find all the orders with status 3 for users that have rep_id = 112:

```
select * from `orders` 
inner join `users` on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
where `status` = 3
and `rep_id` = 112
```

The problem is, the result I'm getting puts the users.id in the id column and in user_id (From orders table) column.

I need the orders.id not the users.id to be in the id column in the results.

Should I just not use Eloquent for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select columns from joined tables: laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437607/how-to-select-columns-from-joined-tables-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: I looked at this post, and tried this:

$sales = Order::where('status', 3)
                    ->with(['user' => function ($q) {
                        $q->where('rep_id', Auth::id());
                    }])                    
                    ->get();
It gave me all the orders and not just the ones for users with rep_id = Auth::id()
The SQL it created:
select * from `orders` where `status` = ?

I also want to be able to use the relationship on it, e.g. do:
foreach($sales as $sale) {
echo $order->user->fullName()
}

Comment: This solved the problem:
$sales = Order::whereHas(
                'user', function ($query) {
            $query->where('rep_id', Auth::id());
        }
    )
    ->with('user')
    ->get();