# How to select record from table whose id is not there in another table using Laravel model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**List item**

I need to select data from a table whose id does not exits in another table or if exists then check other conditions. i can achieve this by

```
Task::join('events','events.task_id' ,'=','tasks.id')
        ->where('events.event_type','=','Task')
        ->where('events.task_stage','!=','assigned')->select('tasks.*');
```

but i don't think this is the right way.

**For Example:**

```
+-------------------------+   +-------------------------+
| tasks                   |   | Events                  |
+----------+--------------+   +-------------------------+
| id       |  name        |   | task_id  |  task_stage  |
| 1        |  Task1       |   | 1        |  'assigned'   |
| 2        |  Task2       |   | 2        |  'created'   |
+----------+--------------+    +----------+--------------+
```

**Result Should be:**

Task with id 2 which is only created not assigned. I am new to queries. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you created your table models?

Comment: yes i have created Models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a `Closure` as the second argument into the `join` method. The `Closure` will receive a `JoinClause` object which allows you to specify constraints on the `join` clause:

```
Task::join('events', function ($join) {
    $join->on('events.task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->where('events.event_type', '=', 'Task')
        ->where('events.task_stage', '!=', 'assigned');
})->select('tasks.*')->get();
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)

Comment: hello @linktoahref there is one more problem now

Comment: The Output record gives the id of events table instead of tasks table.. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727038/laravel-eloquent-how-to-get-only-certain-columns-from-joined-tables/14728992